# Comparing dates not working for different years but working fine for same year

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to compare the following dates with different years and saving status:

```
@date = DateTime.now.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
@valid_to_date = @new_certificate.valid_to.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
if @valid_to_date == @date
  @new_certificate.update_attributes(status: 1)
elsif @valid_to_date > @date
  @new_certificate.update_attributes(status: 2)
elsif @valid_to_date < @date
  @new_certificate.update_attributes(status: 3)
else
end
```

It's working fine for the same years, but for different years, it is not working. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare dates as dates, and not as the specific string format that you wrote, then compare them as dates:

```
@date = Date.today
@valid_to_date = @new_certificate.valid_to.to_date
```

Even if you chose to compare the dates as strings, the comparison goes from the left to right (unless you are using a language like Arabic), so your string format will obviously not work. You also would need padding by zero in appropriate places.